# Three standard six-sided dice are tossed. Calculate the number of 5-spots that you expect to appear

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three standard six-sided dice are tossed. Calculate the number of 5-spots that you expect to appear.

I know that the probability of at least 1 5-spot is $1$ - $(5/6)^3$ = $(91/216)$
So does that mean I should expect $0$ to appear because the probability is less than 1/2?

Comment: Use the linearity of expectation.  How many do you expect to appear in *ONE* roll?

Comment: I would expect 1 5-spot in 6 rolls of one dice

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous You should expect the $5$-spot to appear $\frac16$ times each roll.

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous:  No no no.  How many 1 spots would you expect to see on a single roll?  How many 2 spots?  How many 3 spots?...  How many 6 spots?  If you answer $1$ for each of those... well... you have an amazing contradiction!  Suppose you had a 1000-sided die.  Would you expect to get each one once on a *single* roll????   Think about that...

Comment: Alternatively: Since you *do* expect 1 fivespot *in 6 rolls*, how many should you expect *in 3 rolls*?

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous **Linearity of Expectation**: The expectation of a sum of random variables equals the sum of their expectations. So if $X_1,X_2,X_3$ each represent the count of fivespots on their respective die, then $\sum_{d=1}^3 X_d$ is the count of fivespots on all three dice.  So if you know the expectation for one die, you know the expectation for three. $$\mathsf E(\sum_{d=1}^3 X_d)=\sum_{d=1}^3\mathsf E(X_d)$$ .

Comment: PPS: The expected count may be a fraction.  Expectation is an average (weighted by probability).

Answer (score 4):

For a single dice, you get a 5 spot with probability 1/6 and you don't get a 5 spot with probability 5/6. This is a binary valued random variable (i.e. it is 0 or 1) and it's expected value is simply $1 \times 1/6 + 0 \times 5/6 = 1/6$.

Now, let $X_n$ denote the random variable that is 1 if you got a 5 spot on the $n^{th}$ dice and 0 otherwise. The expected value you are looking to compute is $\mathbb{E}[X_1 + X_2 + X_3] = 3 \times 1/6 = 1/2$ (using linearity of expectation).

You can also do it the hard way:
Let $Y$ denote the number of 5 spots when you roll 3 die. Y can take values 0, 1, 2, or 3.

$\mathbb{P}(Y=0) = (5/6)^3 = 125/216$

$\mathbb{P}(Y=1) = {3 \choose 1}(5/6)^2 (1/6) = 75/216$

$\mathbb{P}(Y=2) = {3 \choose 2}(5/6) (1/6)^2 = 15/216$

$\mathbb{P}(Y=2) = (1/6)^3 = 1/216$

Now compute $\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0 \times 125/216 + 1 \times 75/216 + 2 \times 15/216 + 3 \times 1/216 = 108/216 = 1/2$.